# Como evitar a duplicação de registro em uma tabela no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

**Como faço para nao deixar repetir a placa no cadastro?**

```
<?php

  $placa     =     $_POST['placa'];
  $cidade    =     $_POST['cidade'];
  $estado    =     $_POST['estado'];

$query  = "INSERT INTO veiculos (placa, cidade, estado) 
  VALUES('$placa','$cidade','$estado')";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabei fazendo algumas alterações e deu certo. obrigado pela a LUZ que voce me deu....

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM veiculos WHERE placa = '" . $_POST['placa'] . "'";
 $resulta = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die (mysqli_error($conn));

 if(mysqli_num_rows($resulta) ==0 ){

 } else {


        echo "Cadastro não realizado";

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode definir no banco de dados que a coluna 'placa' seja do tipo UNIQUE, o que não irá permitir dados duplicados ou pode criar na sua página um SELECT que verifique se a placa já exista. Se existir ele retorna uma mensagem de erro, senão ele realiza o INSERT.

Para fazer o SELECT você pode:
1 - SELECT * FROM veiculos WHERE placa = $placa
2 - SELECT placa FROM veiculos WHERE placa = $placa

Diferença: na primeira opção você busca todas as informações do veículo, então se quiser mais dados para comparar pode usar essa, se não tiver necessidade, pode usar a debaixo.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM veiculos WHERE placa = $placa"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query); //Faz select para consultar as placas
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) //checa se a consulta teve alguma linha {
$query  = "INSERT INTO veiculos (placa, cidade, estado) 
  VALUES('$placa','$cidade','$estado')";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query); 
} else {
echo "Erro";
}
```

Comment: como faria esse select?

Comment: @DiogoCarvalho adicionei na resposta

Comment: esta aparecendo esse erro.
    
    Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Faz um teste pra ver o que ele está retornando. Aparentemente ele retorna false, ou seja, não funcionou sua query. Troca o > 0 por == false e inverte o que ele iria fazer (se aparecer false ele da um echo de erro, senão ele faz o outro query.